# Why background image is unable to display on firefox which is able to display on chrome

Tags: html, css

Why background image is unable to display on firefox which is able to display on chrome?
For exapmle:

`background-image: url('C:/Users/SHUBHAM/Documents/Dr.bengers/images/contact-background.jpg') ;`

is able to display on chrome but not on firefox.

Comment: are you sure it isn't cache issue? Try to load page with `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: No its not a cache issue .

Comment: It works fine on chrome. Perhaps something is wrong with your chrome browser. Test your code on a different computer.

Comment: it works on explorer

Comment: works on opera too

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative pathing.

Replace `background-image: url('C:/Users/SHUBHAM/Documents/Dr.bengers/images/contact-background.jpg');`

with

```
background-image: url('images/contact-background.jpg');
```

OR

Maybe it's your browser cache problem. Have you tried clearing **cache** on Firefox? `CMD + SHIFT + R` on Mac or `Ctrl + Shift + R` on Windows

Comment: I did every thing if i replace with background-image: url('images/contact-background.jpg'); even chrome is not showing the  background

Comment: @ShubhamBindage Can you paste page code somewhere? Like Pastebin?

Comment: Okay! i will try!